# oracle - Alter table doesn't work

Tags: sql, oracle

I find this mysql code and when i past it to oracle sql developer the alter table command show me an error when i'v tried to execute it. 
this is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE article (
  code varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  designation varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  num_serie int(50) NOT NULL,
  num_reference int(50) NOT NULL,
  num_inventaire int(50) NOT NULL,
  tva double NOT NULL,
  famille varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  sous_famille varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ;
```

and this is the alter table command :

```
ALTER TABLE article
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (code),
  ADD KEY code (code),
  ADD KEY code_2 (code);
```

this is the error message:

> Rapport d'erreur -
>  ORA-01735: option ALTER TABLE non
>   valide
>   01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
>   *Cause:    
>   *Action:

Comment: why 3 key with the same column?????

Comment: @scaisEdge if i remove the 2 last line, will this solve the problem??

Comment: try   .... you don't show the error message  .. so  .. is difficult .. asnwer

Comment: @scaisEdge i will add the error message. I'm new in this website. thanks

Comment: @scaisEdge I added the error message

Comment: `ADD KEY` is an invalid option. Do you mean to add a UNIQUE constraint? If so use that syntax. Although it doesn't make sense to add such a constraint on a column which is already a primary key. Or a FOREIGN KEY constraint? In which case you need to reference the parent table.

Comment: remove the last 2 (add key)  ..

Comment: You appear to be using MySQL syntax with Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a CREATE TABLE won't work in Oracle (at least, 11gR2). Therefore, I rearranged it a little bit (please, compare column by column yourself to see differences). Primary key constraint can be created *inline* (as I did), at the end of the columns' list (2nd example) or separately, using the ALTER TABLE (3rd example).

Note that you don't have to specify NOT NULL for primary key column(s); Oracle will enforce it itself.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE article (
  2    code           varchar2(20) constraint pk_art primary key,
  3    designation    varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
  4    num_serie      int NOT NULL,
  5    num_reference  int NOT NULL,
  6    num_inventaire int NOT NULL,
  7    tva            number NOT NULL,
  8    famille        varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  9    sous_famille   varchar2(50) NOT NULL
 10  );

Table created.

SQL> drop table article;

Table dropped.

SQL> CREATE TABLE article (
  2    code           varchar2(20),
  3    designation    varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
  4    num_serie      int NOT NULL,
  5    num_reference  int NOT NULL,
  6    num_inventaire int NOT NULL,
  7    tva            number NOT NULL,
  8    famille        varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  9    sous_famille   varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
 10    --
 11    constraint pk_art primary key (code)
 12  );

Table created.

SQL> drop table article;

Table dropped.

SQL> CREATE TABLE article (
  2    code           varchar2(20),
  3    designation    varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
  4    num_serie      int NOT NULL,
  5    num_reference  int NOT NULL,
  6    num_inventaire int NOT NULL,
  7    tva            number NOT NULL,
  8    famille        varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  9    sous_famille   varchar2(50) NOT NULL
 10  );

Table created.

SQL> alter table article add constraint pk_art primary key (code);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using MySQL syntax with Oracle.  I would suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE articles (
  code varchar2(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  designation nvarchar2(100) NOT NULL,
  num_serie number NOT NULL,
  num_reference number NOT NULL,
  num_inventaire number NOT NULL,
  tva number NOT NULL,
  famille varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  sous_famille varchar2(50) NOT NULL
) ;
```

With `code` declared as a primary key, there is no reason to create separate indexes on the column.